# developing for iPhone 4 and 5 still need @2x?

Tags: xcode, iphone-5

if developing for only 3.5 and 4 inch retina screen, do I still need a foo@2x.png?  or can I just do foo.png

Thanks

Comment: It'll look for @2x by default... if it isn't there then it will take it without, assuming the file exists and is in the bundle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your app is ONLY for retina displays then you only need the @2x images and not the regular images.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, yes it is recommended that you have normal image and Hi-res image. On retina device it will automatically get @2x.png version of your image.

If not available then it will take the low res picture.